# Send data from radio button to controller for validation of nested attribute value in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need to send the value of a `radio button` selected from `html` page to `controller`. I have a `Question` model that has `has_many` relationship with `Option` model. The way I am doing it now is like this:

**html.erb**

```
<p>
  <strong>Body:</strong>
  <%= @question.body %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Option:</strong>
  <% @question.options.each do |p| %>
    <%= radio_button_tag('option',p.is_answer) %>
    <%= p.body %>       
  <% end %>
</p>
<p><%= link_to 'Check Answer', check_answer_question_path(@question) %></p>
<p>
  <strong>User:</strong>
  <%= @question.user.email %>
</p>
```

**models**

```
class Question < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :options, dependent: :delete_all, :autosave => true
  serialize :options
  validates_length_of :options, maximum: 4

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :options
end
class Option < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :question
  validates_associated :question
end
```

**controller**

```
def check_answer
  bool_value = p.is_answer
  if(p.is_answer == true)
    do something
  else
    do something else
  end
end

private
    def set_question
      @question = Question.find(params[:id])
    end   

    def question_params
      params.require(:question).permit(:body, options_attributes: [:id, :body, :question_id, :created_at, :updated_at, :is_answer])
    end
```

How can I get the value of `p.is_answer` when a radio button is selected and `Check Answer` button is clicked, in the controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. In your snippet, 'Check Answer' is merely a link. Since you want to send multiple attributes when clicking on it, you probably want to submit a form instead.
2. The second parameter of `radio_button_tag` is the value that your controller will receive in the params. Instead of `p.is_answer`, you probably want to have `p.id`.

[Documentation for forms](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#a-generic-search-form)

[Documentation for radio buttons](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#radio-buttons)

P.S. on why you should send the option's id instead: I'm not sure what your business use case is, but if you want to identify which option the user picked, you want to send an option identifier, i.e. the `id` of the option. Furthermore, a user can send this param without knowing which option is correct. If this is school test, a student could then cheat :)

Comment: Pardon if this is a silly question but why can't I send just the value of `p.is_answer` to the controller?

Comment: Ok. Got it. This is a quiz. So to send the data from radio buttons I should create a form and submit them to controller?

Comment: Yes, and the form should send the option id, so that YOU can check whether the option chosen is correct, instead of letting the user sending "my answer is correct"

Comment: Another thing. When I create a form and submit I will be sending the `option id` to `params`. How will I be able to access the `is_answer` value of the `option`? Should I query the database for that particular `option id`?

Comment: Exactly. Retrieve the option based on its id (`Option,.find(...)`)

Comment: Ok. Initially I was thinking of querying only the `is_answer` column value. I get it now. Thanks!